# adf test result clearly wrong and contrast with kpss test

Tags: time-series

I am running an adf.test in R:

```
x <- rnorm(1000)  # no unit-root
plot(x)
adf.test(x)#p-value = 0.01 thus stationary

y <- diffinv(x)# integrate the stationary series
adf.test(y)# p-value = 0.02847 thus stationary
kpss.test(y)# p-value = 0.01 thus non stattionary
plot(y)
```

clearly this is a normal distribution and the result is stationary by p value
however, I integrate the x series and do adf.test again, the testing p value still imply a stationary process yet the plot is a non stationary process. I use kpss test on the y series and it reject stationary hypothesis. could anyone tell me why adf test make such simply mistake? 
THX!

Answer (score 0):

If you you use the `tseries` package, there is probably a mistake in your code.

I checked back with

```
library(vars)
library(tseries)
x <- rnorm(1000)
plot(x)
summary(ur.df(x))
adf.test(x)

y <- diffinv(x)
plot(y)
summary(ur.df(y,type=c("trend"),lags=1))
adf.test(y,k=1)
summary(ur.kpss(y))
kpss.test(y)
```

which gives me a stationary process for x and a nonstationary process for y. (Note that adf `adf.test` always includes a drift and trend. `ur.df` allows to manually set them.)